# Start-Process -Credential vs -Verb RunAs vs call operator; with SignTool.exe

Tags: powershell, signtool

I am attempting to refactor some code that used to use `Set-AuthenticodeSignature` since I have now bought two code signing certificates that no longer work with that approach.

The vendor that actually provided some support (SSL.Com) suggested using SignTool.exe and I have this working

```
$signTool = "$PSScriptRoot\signtool.exe"
[Void] (& $signTool sign /fd sha256 /tr "http://ts.ssl.com" /n 'Pragmatic Praxis' "$source")
```

The problem is that I am signing multiple things, and with this approach every single call to sign tool.exe requires a manual approval for elevation, which just sucks. So I tried this

```
$signTool = "$PSScriptRoot\signtool.exe"
$arguments = "sign /fd sha256 /tr 'http://ts.ssl.com' /n 'Pragmatic Praxis' '$source'"
Start-Process $signTool -argumentList:$arguments -verb:RunAs
```

And that shows no errors of any kind, and also does absolutely nothing. My understanding is that `-Credential` and `-Verb Runas` are mutually exclusive, so I also tried

```
$UserName = 'Px_Install'
$Credential =  Get-Credential -Message 'Get Password' -User $UserName
$signTool = "$PSScriptRoot\signtool.exe"
$arguments = "sign /fd sha256 /tr 'http://ts.ssl.com' /n 'Pragmatic Praxis' '$source'"
Start-Process $signTool -argumentList:$arguments -Credential:$Credential
```

and that also does absolutely nothing.

Is it even possible these days to sign multiple PowerShell files without a shitshow of multiple UAC approvals? And if so, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why not [(self) elevate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60216595/1701026) your whole script?

Comment: @iron The script IS run elevated. And I still get the retarded Credential Required prompt. But I notice it isn't the standard UAC prompt, it's crypto specific. I only have a few more weeks of dealing with this idiotic Microsoft shitshow before I change careers, so I am really not even sure why I am trying to make using Windows not suck. The only Microsoft (or Autodesk) product that doesn't suck is the one that isn't installed.